# Mockito throwing NPE when calling private method of abstract superclass

Tags: junit, mockito, vert.x

I am currently stuck on a problem for vertx and junit integration

```
public class A extends B implements C {
 @Override
public Maybe<Test> methodToTest(String test) throws IOException {
    Tuple tuple = Tuple.tuple();
    tuple.addString(test);
    return getOne(TEST_QUERY, tuple).map(this::getFromRow).defaultIfEmpty(Test.builder().build()); //getFromRow just convert to object Test
}

}

public abstract class B {
    @Inject
    public MySqlPool mySQLPool;

    public B() {
    }

    public Maybe<Row> getOne(String getOneQuery, Tuple tuple) {
        return this.rxGetOne(getOneQuery, tuple, 300000L);
    }
 private Maybe<Row> rxGetOne(String getOneQuery, Tuple tuple, long timeout) {
        return this.mySQLPool.preparedQuery(getOneQuery).rxExecute(tuple).timeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable).firstElement().switchIfEmpty(Maybe.error(new NotFoundException("Record not found")));
    }

}
```

Created a Test Method : Tried 2 things but getting NPE

```
    A gD=new A();
    Method method = B.class.getDeclaredMethod("getOne", String.class, Tuple.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Tuple t=Tuple.tuple();
    method.invoke(gD,anyString(),t);

    B cut = Mockito.mock(B.class,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    Mockito.when(cut.getOne(anyString(),any())).thenAnswer(I->Maybe.just(r));
```

Please tell me a way I can invoke method of super abstract class and how to mock the methods.